# Reusing literal string in different parts of query

Tags: postgresql, cte, unicode, set-returning-functions

I created this PostgreSQL query while troubleshooting a problem that turned out to be due to non-printing characters in my strings:

```
with cte as ( select 'The character between the xes is evil: xx' as my_bad_string )
select substring( s.my_bad_string, n.i, 1) char_i
  , ascii(substring( s.my_bad_string, n.i, 1)) ascii_char_i
from 
  cte as s
  cross join (
    select generate_series(1, length( 'The character between the xes is evil: xx' ))
  ) n(i)
```

It works. It helped me to find the evil character 141.

Question: what is a more elegant way to write this query so that my hard-coded string appears exactly once instead of twice?

Comment: Note: it seems that stackexchange ate my evil non-printing character. You could get back to the original string by concatenating `||chr(141)||` in between the x's. But really, that's not core to the question.

Comment: It turns out that at least in this situation, "evil character" turned out to be a synonym for "control character". So the actual fix to my problem was along these lines: `regexp_replace('x' || chr(141) || 'x', '[[:cntrl:]]', '', 'g')` to return strings stripped of stuff I didn't want.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) after converting string to array with [`string_to_array()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```
SELECT char_i, ascii(char_i) AS ascii_char_i
FROM   unnest(string_to_array('The character between the xes is evil: xx', NULL)) char_i;
```

`NULL` as separator splits after *every* character in `string_to_array()`.

There is also [`regexp_split_to_table()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), it's more versatile, but also more expensive.

To *guarantee* original order of characters throw `WITH ORDINALITY` into the mix:

```
SELECT pos, char_i, ascii(char_i) AS ascii_char_i
FROM   unnest(string_to_array('The character between the xes is evil: xx', NULL)) WITH ORDINALITY t(char_i, pos)
ORDER  BY pos;
```

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)
- [How get all positions in a field in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34496398/939860)

But while the query is that simple the order is preserved anyway - by the current implementation.

About tricky whitespace and non-printing (UNICODE) characters:

- [Trim trailing spaces with PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22701212/939860)
- [ERROR: "sql " is not a known variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/197324/error-sql-is-not-a-known-variable/197346#197346)

Comment: Thank you. This is lovely. My query was good enough for my immediate needs... but I'm glad I asked. This is *much* cleaner and will come in handy in other situations.